Exclude some tests by tag
Is there a possibility to exclude some tests by tag. E.g.:
npx cucumber-js -t !@foobar

So that all tests executed except tests with tag foobar.

Yes!
cucumber-js --publish-quiet "--tags" "not @norun" "--tags" "not @unstable"

